# phpldapadmin not being able to connect to LDAP server using ldaps

Tags: ssl, tls, ldap

**Update**

I have been able to reproduce the problem in a smaller scale using a simple php script that attempts an LDAP bind. From that script I got more debug output which lets me identify the actual problem. So I am rewriting this question.

## Scenario

I am trying to set up an LDAP environment on my Debian Wheezy server.
I want to secure the communication with the server using a valid SSL certificate (meaning, it is not self signed).
I am using a self compiled version of OpenLDAP because the latest version in the Debian repository does not support SHA2 password hashes.

## Problem Details

I can use this simple php script to try to bind to my LDAP server.

```js
<?php
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
        /* if I remove this, it doesn't work */
        putenv('LDAPTLS_CACERT=/path/to/my/root.ca');
        $uri='ldaps://localhost';
        if (!ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7) ) {
                die('log level option failed\n');
        }
        $ldap = ldap_connect($uri) or die ('connect failed');
        if ( !ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3) ) {
                die('protocol version set failed\n');
        }
        if ( !ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0) ) {
                die('referrals option set failed\n');
        }
        $dn = 'cn=root,dc=domain,dc=tld';
        $pw = '...';
        $bind = ldap_bind($ldap, $dn, $pw);
        if ($bind) {
                echo 'bind succeeded\n';
        } else {
                echo 'bind failed\n';
        }
        ldap_close($ldap);
        echo '<p>blubb</p>';
?>
```

Binding fails and the script produces following messages in my apache error log:

```
ldap_create
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldaps://localhost)
ldap_bind_s
ldap_simple_bind_s
ldap_sasl_bind_s
ldap_sasl_bind
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP localhost:636
ldap_new_socket: 20
ldap_prepare_socket: 20
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying 127.0.0.1:636
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 20 tm: -1 async: 0
TLS: peer cert untrusted or revoked (0x42)
TLS: can't connect: (unknown error code).
ldap_err2string
```

So it is obviously a certificate problem. I guess, that the php ldap library for some reason doesn't find/use my `ldap.conf` (which is located under `/usr/local/etc/openldap`) and therefore doesn't use the TLS_CACERT provided there.
I tried symlinking `/usr/local/etc/openldap/ldap.conf` to `/etc/openldap/ldap.conf`, which normally is the default location. That sadly didn't work either.

**Update**
I was able to get it working by putting

```
putenv('LDAPTLS_CACERT=/path/to/my/root.ca');
```

inside my script. This proves that php doesn't use my `ldap.conf`.
Would it be a reasonable solution to put this enviroment variable in my phpldapadmin configuration?

Other non-php LDAP client tools, such as `ldapsearch` work perfectly.

Does anyone have an idea what could cause the php ldap client library to not find/use my `ldap.conf`?

## System Configuration

### slapd.conf

```
cat /usr/local/etc/openldap/slapd.conf

include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema

pidfile         /var/run/slapd/slapd.pid
argsfile        /var/run/slapd/slapd.args

# self-compiled to enable SHA2 password hash support
modulepath /usr/local/lib
moduleload pw-sha2.so

database        bdb
suffix          "dc=domain,dc=tld"
rootdn          "cn=root,dc=domain,dc=tld"
cachesize       2000

# Use this command to generate a SHA512 hash:
# slappasswd -o module-path=/usr/local/lib -o module-load=pw-sha2.so -h "{SSHA512}"
rootpw          {SSHA512}...

directory       /var/ldap
mode 0600
# Indices to maintain
index   objectClass     eq
index   cn              pres,eq

###############################################################################
# Logging stuff
###############################################################################
loglevel      488

###############################################################################
# TLS stuff
###############################################################################

TLSCipherSuite        ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
TLSCertificateFile    path to certificate file
TLSCertificateKeyFile path to key file
TLSCACertificateFile  path to CA certificate file
TLSVerifyClient       never

###############################################################################
# LDAP security stuff
###############################################################################

password-hash {SSHA512}
security update_tls=256 ssf=256
require authc bind

###############################################################################
# ACLs
###############################################################################

# enable users to change their own password. Everyone else can only use it for auth
#access to * by *
access to attrs=userPassword
       by self write
       by * auth
```

### slapd startup parameters

```
ps aux | grep slapd
ldap      4801  0.0  0.0  73612  7924 ?        Ssl  07:19   0:00 /usr/local/bin/slapd -h ldaps://127.0.0.1:636 -g ldap -u ldap -f /usr/local/etc/openldap/slapd.conf
```

### ldap.conf

```
cat /usr/local/etc/openldap/ldap.conf

BASE    dc=domain,dc=tld
URI     ldaps://127.0.0.1:636

#TLS_REQCERT     never
TLS_CACERT      path to CA certificate file
```

### phpldapadmin config.php (all comments removed)

```
<?php
  $config->custom->debug['level'] = 255;
  $config->custom->debug['syslog'] = true;
$config->custom->appearance['friendly_attrs'] = array(
    'facsimileTelephoneNumber' => 'Fax',
    'gid'                      => 'Group',
    'mail'                     => 'Email',
    'telephoneNumber'          => 'Telephone',
    'uid'                      => 'User Name',
    'userPassword'             => 'Password'
);
   $config->custom->modify_member['attr'] = 'dn';


$servers = new Datastore();
$servers->newServer('ldap_pla');
$servers->setValue('server','name','domain.tld LDAP server');
/* according to documentation port must be provided in URI and server->port
 * must be 0 when using ldaps
 */
$servers->setValue('server','host','ldaps://127.0.0.1:636');
$servers->setValue('server','port',0);
$servers->setValue('server','base',array('dc=domain,dc=tld'));
$servers->setValue('login','auth_type','session');
$servers->setValue('login','bind_id','cn=root,dc=domain,dc=tld');
/* no need to enable this, if ldap is running on port 636 with ldaps:// */
$servers->setValue('server','tls',false);
$servers->setValue('login','anon_bind',false);
?>
```

### LDAP DB content (Just getting started ;) )

```
slapcat

dn: dc=domain,dc=tld
dc: domain
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organizationalUnit
structuralObjectClass: organizationalUnit
entryUUID: c2dc8e83-77a6-47ca-b245-f74636aca48f
creatorsName: cn=root,dc=domain,dc=tld
createTimestamp: 20140928123911Z
ou: domain.tld
entryCSN: 20140929080227.350590Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=root,dc=domain,dc=tld
modifyTimestamp: 20140929080227Z
```

## What I tried

To ensure this is not a SSL configuration problem I invoked:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:636 -CAfile /path/to/CA_certificate.file -verify 5 

CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = IL, O = StartCom Ltd., OU = Secure Digital Certificate Signing, CN = StartCom Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=1 C = IL, O = StartCom Ltd., OU = Secure Digital Certificate Signing, CN = StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA
verify return:1
depth=0 description = BNw48VehLnkei38O, C = DE, CN = domain.tld, emailAddress = webmaster@domain.tld
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/description=<stripped>/C=DE/CN=domain.tld/emailAddress=webmaster@domain.tld
   i:/C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing/CN=StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA
 1 s:/C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing/CN=StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA
   i:/C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing/CN=StartCom Certification Authority
 2 s:/C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing/CN=StartCom Certification Authority
   i:/C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing/CN=StartCom Certification Authority
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<stripped>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/description=BNw48VehLnkei38O/C=DE/CN=domain.tld/emailAddress=webmaster@domain.tld
issuer=/C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing/CN=StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5739 bytes and written 891 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 4096 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: <stripped>
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: <stripped>
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    <stripped>

    Start Time: 1412055431
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

ldapsearch works perfectly:

```
su www-data -c 'ldapsearch -H "ldaps://localhost" -b "dc=domain,dc=tld" -s base "dc=domain,dc=tld" -D "cn=root,dc=domain,dc=tld" -w"<stripped>" -v -d256'
ldap_initialize( ldaps://localhost:636/??base )
filter: dc=domain,dc=tld
requesting: All userApplication attributes
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=domain,dc=tld> with scope baseObject
# filter: dc=domain,dc=tld
# requesting: ALL
#

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 1
```

## Versions

These are the versions of the relevant software packages I use:

### OpenLDAP (self compiled)

```
slapd -V
@(#) $OpenLDAP: slapd 2.4.39 (Sep 28 2014 22:28:35)
```

### PHP

```
php --version
PHP 5.4.4-14+deb7u14 (cli) (built: Aug 21 2014 08:36:44)
```

### Apache

```
apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
Server built:   Jul 24 2014 15:34:00
```

### phpldapadmin (from SID)

```
cat /usr/share/phpldapadmin/VERSION
RELEASE-1.2.2
```

Sorry for this very long question. I hope someone is able to help me, because I'm pretty much out of ideas.
Thanks a lot for any help in advance!

Comment: Did you check syslog for slapd entries? Maybe also increase the loglevel (see slapd.conf man page).

Comment: The syslog snipped above contains a few lines of slapd output (such as that a TLS connection has been established).  But I will increase the loglevel and post results

Comment: Raised loglevel to 488 now. I added the additional output in the log above

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem in a smaller scale and could therefore simplify the question and identify the actual problem. the php ldap library doesn't seem to find/use my ldap.conf. I rewrote the question

Comment: And another update: I was able to 'solve' it, by putting a LDAPTLS_CACERT enviroment variable in my script. Would it be a reasonable solution to put this environment variable somewhere in the phplapadmin sources? Also updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was able to solve it.
I needed a symlink from `/usr/local/etc/openlad/ldap.conf` to `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf`

Comment: Do you mean `/usr/local/etc/openldap/ldap.conf`?  Or maybe `/usr/local/etc/ldap/ldap.conf`?  Why is your system looking for the config file there?